# How to delete cache files everytime a user access my website with iOS' Safari?

Tags: php, html, css, safari

I am quite new to Web Development, recently I made a simple website without using any framework. I make sure to follow the "Responsive Web Design" to make my website mobile-friendly. I was testing my website on several devices such as: Desktop(Firefox and Chrome) and Mobile (iOS Safari), however there was a time, after editing my CSS files, the CSS rules are not loaded properly, therefore my intended styles for the mobile website was not applied to the HTML tags.

I found a solution to this problem, which was to delete all website caches on the iOS device, after I did it, re-accessed the website and the website was displayed as intended.

Is there any way to delete/refresh the caches stored for my website on the device?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add query parameters to the file. Which would basically would look something like this

```
<script src="/path/to/your-script.js?v=1.0.01"></script>
```

You could do the same with all your static files (CSS, JS, images). Every time you change the value of "v" it would force Safari to re-download the file. This is more of a production hack to force users to download new version of static files though.

Ultimately on your development server you want to disable browser caching with headers coming from your server (be it Apache, Nginx or whatever). Safari respects those.

If you are using PHP to spit out your HTML you can use the following code to make sure you always have dynamic variables

```
<script src="/path/to/your-script.js?js=<?= time(); ?>"></script>
```

This will basically invalidate browser cache each second.

Comment: Okay thanks, do you have any reference as to what "v" value is and how could it be able to do this?

Comment: "v" is a made-up variable by me. It's a HTTP query parameter. You can basically replace "v" with anything you wish. I used "v" as an acronym for "version". Browser caching occurs on URL level, so any change in the URL (as-in, adding/changing query parameters) would force the browser to redownload the file.